# django form custom widget for a "ListField" and displaying a list

Tags: python, django, forms, ldap, widget

Using django-ldapdb, I'm trying to manage user ssh keys stored in our ldap directory. The main problem I have is that when a [ListField](http://opensource.bolloretelecom.eu/projects/django-ldapdb/browser/trunk/ldapdb/models/fields.py#L121) is displayed on a ModelForm, it renders an input with a repr'd list as a unicode string when the actual datatype returned by ListField.to_python() is a list.

What is the best way to write a custom widget that would turn that list into a set of input boxes or any custom html? The end goal is something which looks very similar to [this](http://www.digitalprognosis.com/pics/mango.png) so that a user could easily add new ssh keys or remove existing ones. The existing stuff like in that screenshot of mango will only display the ssh key fingerprint and "comment" or email instead of the raw key.

Bonus points to anyone who can figure out a way to hook up some jQuery and make it similar to the django admin inline pretty (google django jquery admin and click the djangoadvent article. I don't have enough SO points to link it).

How would you implement something like this?